# Website domain name does not opens and IP address opens

Tags: dns, ip, ping

I have a problem to access to a website I am working for. When I type in their website domain the web browser shows "This webpage is not available". I also try to ping domain name from command prompt and same problem.

However when I type in website IP address, it works without any problems, I also successfully ping it.

I also noticed that when I use proxy with different IP address then my default one I can access website on both, domain and IP. I tried so many things and none of them works so I am without options.

Any suggestions are most welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your internett adress provider that the adress www.somehost.com is directed properly to that ip adress using dns redirecting?

Comment: no I havent checked that. I did called them and they gave me instructions to set a different DNS on my computer, but that didnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

May be the DNS cache of your proxy is not refreshed. It can take up to 48 hours for the cache to refresh.

Regards,
Lanex